# UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds always zero

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the screen width to display a different image on iPhone 6. However `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds` is always zero when I check width or height. Any idea why?

Comment: Where in your code is that line?

Comment: I have tried in viewDidAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @LyndseyScott Thanks for your help but I got it working with Leonardo's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let height = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height

let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width
```

Comment: This worked. I was accessing bounds.size.width which wasn't working. Any idea why? I thought that was the correct way to access it.